# Split the list based on number sequence

Tags: c#

I have a list of numbers like

```
example list = [ 1,2,3,5,10,11]
```

I want to split the list based on sequence

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [5]
list3 = [10,11]
```

But I am confused how to bring this to the code can anyone please help me regarding this, Thanks.

Comment: Your example makes no sense, are you sure `list2` should be in that output? Are you looking to create multiple lists where the numbers are in sequence from the first list?

Comment: You haven't provided any rules. To make a guess, you mean that you want to break it into sets of numbers where the difference between them is 1? Why does list2 exist? Perhaps there's a different rule?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Yes Exactly

Comment: This has been asked many times before, I've linked a few. Please search a bit harder next time :)

Comment: @DavidG Sorry for the wrong input I have corrected it now.